# Why can't Gradle find the javadoc executable?

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, opensearch

I am attempting to build this project:

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop#writing-2

Here is the Gradle configuration:

```
===========================================
OpenSearch-Hadoop Build Hamster says Hello!
===========================================
Min runtime: 1.8
Building version [1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Testing against OpenSearch [2.7.0-SNAPSHOT] with Lucene [9.5.0-snapshot-a4ef70f]
Using Gradle [8.1.1]
Using Apache Hadoop on YARN [3.1.2]
=======================================
OpenSearch Build Hamster says Hello!
  Gradle Version        : 8.1.1
  OS Info               : Windows 10 10.0 (amd64)
  JDK Version           : 11 (Oracle JDK)
  JAVA_HOME             : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
  Random Testing Seed   : DBEBD3C9481699C
  In FIPS 140 mode      : false
=======================================
```

**Error during build: **

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':opensearch-hadoop-mr:javadoc'.
> Error while evaluating property 'javadocTool' of task ':opensearch-hadoop-mr:javadoc'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':opensearch-hadoop-mr:javadoc' property 'javadocTool'.
      > The configured executable does not exist (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\javadoc)
```

When checking the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\javadoc, the javadoc.exe is present. I have tried the following:

- Changing the JAVA_HOME and JAVA8_HOME variables
- Adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH,
- Disabling javadoc tasks in the build.gradle file:
      `tasks.withType(Javadoc).all {  enabled = false }`

Any help is appreciated as to why the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\javadoc.exe` file is not found and the build fails. Thank you

Comment: Notice it says `...\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\javadoc` and not `javadoc.exe`.  Sounds like a Linux/Windows mixup... or a path specification error.  Also, it's not clear why the gradle config says JDK-11 but the error message refers to JDK-8.

Comment: Your own snippet shows it is using a different Java version: `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to build the sources? Can you not pull the dependency?

Comment: Hi, All thank you for the replies. I am fairly new to java, I was following the instructions on this github page. https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop. I have 3 jdks installed:

"To create a distributable zip, run gradlew distZip from the command line; once completed you will find the jar in build/libs.
To build the project, JVM 8, JVM 11, and JVM 17 are required. The minimum compiler version is Java 14 and the minimum runtime is Java 8."